Cannot install R package unigd 0.1.1 on Windows 11 for R4.1.0
I cannot install the unigd v0.1.1 package in R v4.1.0 on my Windows11 laptop. Rtools40 is installed and on the PATH.
I get the following error:
r$> install.packages("unigd", dependencies = T)
...
/mingw32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o unigd.dll tmp.def base_64.o compress.o cpp11.o draw_data.o page_store.o plot_history.o r_thread_posix.o r_thread_win32.o renderer_cairo.o renderer_json.o renderer_meta.o renderer_strings.o renderer_svg.o renderer_tikz.o renderers.o unigd.o unigd_dev.o unigd_external.o uuid.o -L../windows/harfbuzz-2.7.4/lib/i386 -lpng -lz -L../windows/cairo-1.16.0/lib/i386 -lcairo -lfreetype -lpixman-1 -lharfbuzz -lbz2 -liconv -lgdi32 -ltiff -ltiffxx -ljpeg -lzstd -lwebp -lsharpyuv -llzma -LC:/<MY_INSTALL_DIR>/R/R-41~1.0/bin/i386 -lR
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lzstd
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwebp
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsharpyuv
C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llzma
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'unigd'

The package is required by httpgd v2.0.1 which is recommended to view R graphics in VScode.
Thanks for your help!
Edit
R sessionInfo():
r$> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 cli_3.6.1      tools_4.1.0    jsonlite_1.8.8 rlang_1.1.3    renv_1.0.3

I just noticed it says Win10, although I updated to Win11 and am still using the already installed R version.

My workaround is to stay with httpgd v1.3.1 https://github.com/cran/httpgd/tags

I can install both the CRAN binary and from source without issues, which means the issue is related to your setup. Can you provide more information regarding that setup?

After updating the OS, I would reinstall R and RTools.
